# Send traffic through another node

Tags: ssh, networking

All machines are running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I'm pretty new to linux and have a problem to query a service running on a testing node (***TN***) in order to debug my application (some Java application).

The thing is the service running on TN may be accessed only from a specific middle node (***MN***) which I can access through ***ssh***. So my question is if it's possible to send all outcoming traffic to ***TN*** from my working machine through ***MN***?

Or maybe there are another common workaround for that case?

Is it even possible?

Comment: The most common solution to this is ssh port forwarding.  Take a look at http://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html for some ideas